# Optimization in QList

Tags: qt, qlist

I want to optimize my code but i'm not sure, if it's worth to check, if the list is empty before calling clear?

```
if ( !myContainers.isEmpty() ) {
  myContainers.clear();
}
```

isEmpty is just a size == 0 check. What about clear? Does it iterates over all Elements and calls remove or is it so fast internally that it wouldn't make a difference?

Comment: I think you'd get better help on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: From my experience, these lines are definitely not your code bottleneck. So I would go for the simplest solution which is that you should only call `clear()`. And if you really want to optimize your code, you should run your code in profiler to find the bottleneck or bottlenecks. Then you will know what spots in your code to optimize.

Comment: Actually the only situation when checking for `isEmpty()` can make some difference is when your list has already some space allocated (e.g. with `reserve()`) and you could reuse this space again. In that case you could save one extra dynamic allocation, which is rather slow operation. Only in this very special case it makes sense to think about checking for `isEmpty()`. If this is not your case, I would just call `clear()`.

Comment: Calling `isEmpty()` before clearing the list container (QList) is redundant. According to the implementation of `QList::clear()` it just replaces itself with an empty `QList`.